# Bokeh + Angular2/4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, bokeh

Does anyone have an example of a proper way to embed Bokeh chart into Angular2/4 web application? I tried to render with html string with Bokeh script and div through innerHTML tag and sanitation pipes with no success.

Comment: Can you give more details on what exactly you were doing that didn't work? Ideally, some reproducible code examples.

Comment: this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55049649/4497962 please look for our example there.